# How can I set my Widgets's position from the API?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried this but didn't work

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextManger textManger = TextManger();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: StreamBuilder<List<TextM>>(
          stream: textManger.contactListView,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (snapshot.data[0].x.toDouble() / 100),
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (snapshot.data[0].y.toDouble() / 100),
                  // left: snapshot.data[0].x.toDouble()  ,
                  // top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * snapshot.data[0].y.toDouble()  / 100 ,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: snapshot.data[0].rotate.toDouble() * math.pi / 180,
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.data[0].textContent,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: HexColor(snapshot.data[0].color),
                        fontSize: snapshot.data[0].fontSize.toDouble(),
                        // fontSize: snapshot.data[0].fontSize.toDouble(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain better what you're trying to do?

Comment: I wanna get data from API 
and set that data to set a position for the text widget 
but can't work 
ex:
I wanna set the position to be on the center like I get on the API 
...
{
text: {
fontSize: 50,
color: "#9bc924",
fontFamily: "cairo",
x: 50,
y: 50,
rotate: 180,
italic: true,
textContent: "Mo Salah"
}
}
...